# ClassNotFoundException after adding the jar to the lib folder of a Tomcat Service installation

Tags: java, class, jar, tomcat7

I'm trying to update a web app to use DBCP. Things are running great locally (typical Tomcat on Windows installation). However, on the DEV server (EC2 LINUX AMI; Tomcat as a Service) I am getting the following

```
Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
```

I have narrowed this down (I think) to the `/lib` folder originally not having `tomcat-jdbc.ja`.

I have since added this jar, and restarted the Tomcat instance with the following...

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

However, I still get the same ClassNotFoundException. How can I get the Tomcat service to recognize `tomcat-dbcp.jar`?

EDIT - Here's the stack trace when after running `sudo service tomcat7 start`

```
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with JAR file [/usr/share/java/tomcat7/log4j.jar], exists: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with JAR file [/usr/share/java/tomcat7/log4j.jar], exists: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1404 ms
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 20, 2014 5:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12969 ms
```

Comment: Can you include the full call stack from the logging in the logs folder?

Comment: Sure, just edited with the stacktrace

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else has this issue, here's how I resolved it.

In my context.xml file I had to had the following attribute to the  tag

```
factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
```

... so my final  tag looked something like....

```
<Resource name="jdbc/resourceName"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    logAbandoned="false" 
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWait="10000"
    username= "username"
    password="password"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    url="jdbc:mysql://your.mysql.host"/>
```

Basically, I just forced it to revert back to not use Tomcat's DBCP class.